# Where is the netbook edition?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I can't find the new `11.04` version of the netbook edition on the ubuntu webpages. Also my [mirror](http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/releases.ubuntu.com//natty/) does not contain any netbook iso's.

Has Ubuntu for Netbooks died?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's merged into the Desktop edition.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Netbook_Edition):

> Beginning with version 10.10, Ubuntu Netbook Edition uses the Unity desktop as its desktop interface. The classic netbook interface was available in Ubuntu's software repositories as an option.
>
> Because Ubuntu's desktop edition has moved to the same Unity interface as the netbook edition, starting with Ubuntu 11.04 **the netbook edition has been merged into the desktop edition.**

---

[Here is](http://blog.canonical.com/?p=528) a post from canonical blog which explains more:

[Ubuntu Netbook Edition folded into Ubuntu for next release](http://blog.canonical.com/?p=528)

> One of the benefits of the direction that’s been taken with the next release of Ubuntu is that there is no longer a need for a separate netbook edition. The introduction of the new shell for Ubuntu means that we have a user interface that works equally well whatever the form factor of the PC. And the underlying technology works on a range of architectures including those common in netbook, notebooks, desktops or whatever you choose to run it on. Hence the need for a separate version for netbooks is removed...

So, there won't be an Ubuntu Netbook edition for future cycles - if you want to install Ubuntu on your Netbook, the normal desktop install will work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

There is no netbook version of Natty, just use the regular version, they have been combined into one.

Comment: Thanks. It's odd that it came up in the wubi installer...

Comment: I don't, maybe just a relic from days gone by?

Comment: Nah, I just downloaded the installer today.

Comment: Yeah I know... what I am saying is, that maybe it was a link that they thought they were going to use, because in the past they would have, but never removed it, after the release...

Comment: Oh, oh, I see, okay, yes, probably.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it merged with the desktop version.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no separate editions to download, Both netbook and desktop versions are included in the Ubuntu.iso . this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/the-end-of-ubuntu-netbook-edition-the-return-of-ubuntu/) will explain it briefly.

Answer (score 3):

Since Unity there is no seperate Netbook Edition, Ubuntu and Ubuntu Netbook are the same thing now.