# Cannot download Ubuntu Netbook Edition

Tags: 11.04, windows-7, wubi, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the netbook edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37568/where-is-the-netbook-edition)

Windows 7 - Acer

I tried to download the Netbook version today (because I am on a netbook, of course) and it told me that it could not download the torrent link. If I try downloading the Desktop version, it works fine, and starts the download.

Solutions?

((This is the Wubi install))