# Ubuntu 11.04 netbook edition

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the 11.04 netbook edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37568/where-is-the-11-04-netbook-edition)

i already have 11.04 installed on my Acer one netbook but i have some problems with it.its slugish sometimes
do they have netbook remix for 11.04 as they had it for 10.04?

Comment: The desktop and netbook versiuion of Ubuntu were merged, that's how we ended up with Unity (not complaining, I like it).

Answer (score 0):

There are no netbook remix for 11.04 on the [Official download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#bt).

Same goes for their [Release page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/).

So it seems like there are no official remix, but as far as I know the netbook remix was mainly focused on compatibility with netbook hardware, so if your computers hardware is detected ( webcam, cardreader, graphic card ) then you would not gain that much by using a netbook remix.

Slugishness can be the symptom of many things, my tips is to check if you have some zombieprocesses or some processes that hog the cpu.
This can be done with `System Monitor`.

One more reason might that your harddrive might be getting old/damaged, one way to check is to use `Disk Utility` and do a `Benchmark` and select `Start Read-Only Benchmark`. While in `Disk Utility` you can check the `SMART Status`if your harddrive supports it, do not that S.M.A.R.T. isn't realy working for SSD as far as I know.