# Is there an Ubuntu 12.04 netbook edition?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the netbook edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37568/where-is-the-netbook-edition)

Is there a separate Ubuntu 12.04 netbook edition? This page http://www.ubuntu.com/download does not show one. However, my older 10.04 had separate editions for desktop and netbook.