# Installing Ubuntu on Netbook

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I have a netbook, I already installed Ubuntu12.04 but It has so many errors and problems.
I think It will be better to instal UNE on it, I searched ubuntu.com but I couldn't find UNE version for netbook to download. There are only regular versions for PC and etc.
How can I download Ubuntu for netbook(UNE)?

I read about it, They said after 12.04 Desktop version is combined with Netbook one, so any one can use it! But it's a lie!  It's not working properly, Should I instal 10.10 again?

Comment: First check if your netbook will work with UNE :https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuNetbookEdition#Will_my_netbook_work_with_UNE.3F

Comment: UNE is deprecated. You will not find it for 12.04. See  http://askubuntu.com/questions/37568/where-is-the-netbook-edition. To get help on installing Ubuntu including any official derivative we need more information on your hardware and on your issues. Please [edit] your question for that.

Comment: As UNE is deprecated, you might want to create a new question regarding fixing the problems you are experiencing.
Ps. If by errors you mean a small popup window telling you "Something has crashed" (or similar), then you most likely should not be worried, thats just a oversensitive bug reporter.